# Did Mac os have `tcp_fin_timeout` options?

Tags: macos, tcp

in linux we have `tcp_fin_timeout` to close the connection when the other side never send fin to us. but in macos i do not see anything like this.

so i consider `user timer`(described in tcp) to force close connection.

but it seems do not apply in linux and mac, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

To check the current "fin timeout" in macOS simply try this:
`$ sysctl -a | egrep fin_timeout`